# Struggling with LDAP query base DN vs filter

Tags: active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

I'm trying to pull out a list of users from Active Directory with LDAP. I want to get all users from multiple OUs and I'm struggling to get results.

In an attempt to simplify things, I tried setting a single OU as the base DN and just filtering to get user objects :

```
ldapsearch -b "OU=Company Users,OU=Users,OU=UK,OU=Helpdesk,DC=ad,DC=company,DC=com" '(objectClass=user)'
```

This successfully returns lots of users. However, if I move some of the elements from the base DN to the filter, I get no results at all..

```
ldapsearch -b "DC=ad,DC=company,DC=com" '(&(objectClass=user)(OU=Company Users)(OU=Users)(OU=UK)(OU=Helpdesk))'
```

Aren't these two queries essentially the same?

Am I being daft? (no doubt, there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not the same.

From ywhat you related, you want:
ldapsearch -b "OU=Company `Users,OU=Users,OU=UK,OU=Helpdesk,DC=ad,DC=company,DC=com" '(objectClass=user)'`

The baseDN

`OU=Company OU=Users,OU=Users,OU=UK,OU=Helpdesk,DC=ad,DC=company,DC=com`

represents a branch in the "tree" structure.

The

`(OU=Company Users)(OU=Users)(OU=UK)(OU=Helpdesk)`

Represents attributes on the user entries and I doubt that anyone populated the attributes.

It is unfortunate that Microsoft Active Directory does not support the "normal" "[ExtensibleMatch](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Wiki.jsp?page=ExtensibleMatch)" filters.

Let me know how I can help.

Comment: So you can only filter on object attributes? I was hoping to use a filter to select all user objects but from a few different locations in the tree..

Comment: Looks like I’ll need to query for all user objects below the base DN and then filter the results in code..

Comment: You could raise your base to a higher level or, preferable if you do this a lot,  populate the users with the attributes you need.

Comment: The base DN is as deep as I can go without excluding some of the OUs I need to get users from. If I can't filter by OU, the only option is to pull all users and filter it myself.